# Non-parallel, non-sequential circuit

Tags: voltage, resistance, ohms-law

This is the circuit: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVk5Y.png]

I've simulated it and got a current of 30.76mA at the voltage source (5V).
With this I've calculated the total resistance to be 162.5 Ohm.
Each resistors is 100 Ohms big.

But why is this the case?
My first (and only) intuition for the resistance was R_t = 100 + (100 || 200 || 200) = 150 Ohm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to simplify.

Starting from the furthest point away from the power source, combine the resistors in pairs and replace those pairs with a single resistor.  Keep going until you have only one resistor.

\$R_3\$ and \$R_6\$ add together to form a single resistor.  That new resistor (we'll call it \$R_{36}\$) is then in parallel with \$R_5\$. Combine those to make a new resistor \$R_{536}\$.  Keep going like that until you have just one resistor left.

That resistor is known as the "Thevenin equivalent resistance".

Comment: Perfect. The missing information for me was to start from the right.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the eqivalent resistance being 162.5 Ohms, but there is little we can do to verify this through a direct approach without knowing the values of each resistor in your schematic.

All I can help you with is to say that you would go about this by simply using the relationships between series/parallel resistors starting from the far right.

\$R_E\$ = ((\$R_5\$||(\$R_6\$ + \$R_2\$)) + \$R_2\$) || \$R_4\$) +\$R_1\$